# How to stop windows media player from "Updating media library"?

Tags: windows-10, windows-media-player

I am using Windows media player in Windows 10 and would like to stop the annoying "Updating media library" which seems to be ongoing all the time. I followed the instructions I found [HERE](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-media-player-is-constantly-updating-media/ed6794c4-4543-45a3-b855-e5fb166ad0a1), but this does not work. The player is still "updating"(?) all the time. How to stop it? And what the heck is that player actually updating ????

Comment: You might need to remove check marks to  "Add local media files to library when played." “Add remote media files to library when played.” etc. as a different user, i.e., both as Administrator and user. Also, if you don't use those features, try another player, such as VLC, MPC-HC, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you try rebuilding WMP's library by following these instructions. First note that resetting the library will make you lose all current play counts, and possibly ratings too. Then, follow these steps:

- Reboot the PC.
- Go to Start, type `services.msc` in the Search field, and press Enter. In Services, find the `Windows Media Player Network Sharing Service`. If its status is `Started`, double-click the service and click `Stop`.
- Go to Start, type `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft` in the Search field, and press Enter. This folder will open up in Windows Explorer.
- In this folder, delete the `Media Player` folder. If you can't see the folder, then it's probably hidden. Set Explorer to show hidden files and folders, and to show protected system files.
- Start WMP, your library will have been reset and will be rebuilt. Check if the issue still occurs.